# Como convertir este código para que guarde varios archivos en el servidor

Tags: php, fileupload

Tengo el siguiente código PHP que recibe los datos mediante Ajax, este guarda correctamente el archivo que se le indica en la carpeta destino

```
<?php

    if (isset($_FILES['archivo'])) {
        $archivo = $_FILES['archivo'];
        $archivo_nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
        $extension = pathinfo($archivo['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $ruta1= $_POST['nombreTipoUnidad'];
        $ruta2= $_POST['nombreProyectoUnidad'];
        $Empleado_Carga= $_POST['numeroEmpleadoSession'];
        $nombre = "{$_POST['numeroEmpleadoSession']}_{$_POST['nombreProyectoUnidad']}_$archivo_nombre";
        if (move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], "resguardos/$ruta1/$ruta2/$nombre"))
   {
   echo 1;
   } else {
   echo 0;
   }
 }
?>
```

Agrega todo los datos que le indico, pero he intentado hacer una replica para otra función donde me reciba múltiples archivos y no me funciona. Esto es lo que intente, pero algo me falta ya revise algunos blogs, y no encuentro donde pudiera estar mal:

```
<?php
    foreach($_FILES["resguardos"]['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
    {
        if (isset($_FILES['resguardos']['name'][$key])) {
            $archivo = $_FILES['resguardos'][$key];
            $archivo_nombre = $_FILES['resguardos']['name'][$key];
            $extension = pathinfo($archivo['name'][$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $ruta1= $_POST['nombreTipoUnidad'];
            $ruta2= $_POST['nombreProyectoUnidad'];
            $Empleado_Carga= $_POST['numeroEmpleadoSession'];
            $nombre = "{$_POST['numeroEmpleadoSession']}_{$_POST['nombreProyectoUnidad']}_$archivo_nombre";


        if (move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], "resguardos/$ruta1/$ruta2/$nombre"))
   {
   echo 1;
   } else {
   echo 0;
   }
           
}
?>
```

Espero me puedan indicar como resolver de antemano gracias!!.

Comment: Si son varios archivos, el `foreach` debería ser sobre `$_FILES`, es decir `foreach($_FILES as $file)`, o si todos los campos de archivo tienen `name="resguardos"` asumo que vuelve como un array, entonces sería `foreach($_FILES['resguardos'] as $file)`

Comment: No es necesario guardar `$key` ni usar `isset`, si el foreach hace el loop sobre un elemento del array significa que existe.

Comment: @Gonzalingui Ok lo pruebo y te comento como me va!!. Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El ciclo lo estás ejecutando correctamente, sobre una de las propiedades y usando el mismo índice para acceder al resto. El problema es que después tratas de acceder con índices que no existen, por ejemplo:

```
$archivo = $_FILES['resguardos'][$key];
```

En esa línea, `$key` es numérico y no existe el elemento en `$_FILES['resguardos']`, con archivos múltiples, se crea un arreglo por cada propiedad:

- tmp_name: Nombre y ubicación del archivo temporal
- name: Nombre real del archivo
- type: Tipo MIME, poco confiable
- size: Tamaño del archivo en bytes
- error: [Código de error](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Entonces, debes acceder a ellas con `$_FILES[nombre-de-archivo][nombre-de-propiedad][índice]`

```
<?php
foreach($_FILES["resguardos"]['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
    if (isset($_FILES['resguardos']['name'][$key])) {
        // Obtener ubicación de archivo temporal
        $archivo = $_FILES['resguardos']['tmp_name'][$key];
        // Se puede hacer directamente con
        // $archivo = $tmp_name; // Así está definida la variable en el ciclo
        $archivo_nombre = $_FILES['resguardos']['name'][$key];
        // Obtener extensión desde el nombre real
        $extension = pathinfo($archivo_nombre, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $ruta1= $_POST['nombreTipoUnidad'];
        $ruta2= $_POST['nombreProyectoUnidad'];
        $Empleado_Carga= $_POST['numeroEmpleadoSession'];
        $nombre = "{$_POST['numeroEmpleadoSession']}_{$_POST['nombreProyectoUnidad']}_$archivo_nombre";

        if (move_uploaded_file($archivo, "resguardos/$ruta1/$ruta2/$nombre")) {
            echo 1;
        } else {
            echo 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: listo @Triby nada mas tuve que modificar dos lineas y ya me guardo tres archivos.  Excelente aportación

Comment: hice otro test y subió 8 archivos sin problema, lo único raro es que me arroja el swal alert del error en lugar del swal que indica que fueron guardados con éxito.

Comment: Probablemente `swal` espera solo 1 o 0 y, si son varios archivos saldrá 1111 o 1101, dependiendo del resultado de cada archivo.

Comment: Crea otra pregunta con el código Javascript para ver cómo puede solucionarse, aunque ya tengo una idea, pero es mejor ver lo que tienes.

Comment: Un poco mas tarde subo eso que me pides, me voy a ocupar en una video reunión de desarrollo